# Docker Compose Error make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run command `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate` and encountered this issue. There are suggestions from docker forums that upgrading to **Docker 20** will make it work but I am currently using **Docker 24**

**Bash**

```
make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:191: bcmath.lo] Error 127
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install     bcmath     intl     mbstring     mysqli     opcache     pdo_mysql     simplexml     soap     sockets     sodium     xsl     zip     && pecl install mongodb' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.16

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    acl \
    bash \
    curl-dev \
    curl \
    git \
    icu-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    linux-headers \
    oniguruma-dev \
    openssh \
    nano \
    sqlite-dev \
    supervisor \
    tzdata \
    vim \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS

RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Manila /etc/localtime

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    intl \
    mbstring \
    mysqli \
    opcache \
    pdo_mysql \
    simplexml \
    soap \
    sockets \
    sodium \
    xsl \
    zip \
    && pecl install mongodb

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && sed -i "/history-search-/s/^#//g" /etc/inputrc \
    && sed -i "/export PS1/a export HISTSIZE=10000" /etc/profile

EXPOSE 9001
```

Comment: when i connect to shell from alpine container. i use `docker exec -it [container_id] sh` because use bash or bin/bash fired error like you. so imho maybe this is similar issue this. alpine linux maybe not include bash default

Comment: @player1 it's strange, it was built on Docker 20.10.12 (ubuntu 20.04) with docker build command (copied and built your dockerfile).

Comment: @rodpold I am currently building the container so connecting inside will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same scenario with me that I have updated `Docker 24` and still encounter a problem. Try downgrading the Alpine version.
In my original Dockerfile I have

**FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.16**

and downgraded it to

**FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13**

and it works!

Note: If you are also using `PHP 8.0`, `PHP 8.1`, and `PHP 8.2` using alpine greater than `Alpine 3.14` will also not work on `Docker 24`